# PHP details and info about an IP

Tags: php, html

I want a way to get the IP details like country name. I am getting the IP address using this code :

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

But I don't know how to get info of that IP.

Comment: Look at the PHP [GeoIP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)

Comment: You will need to pay for a service that provides this data based on an IP address. You can take a look at [MaxMind](http://maxmind.com) for solutions for this. I use them for looking up info on an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP address ranges are assigned to top providers that usually represent countries. The ranges are subdivided and sold to sub regions. This covers 90% of the case, although some ISPs can cover multiple countries, and addresses get bought and sold all the time. A commercial database is actively maintained. You may use such database (one example would be the MaxMind GeoIP database) to perform a reverse IP lookup. i.e. (IP -> geo division). There's no deterministic/mathematical way to look at the IP and "figure out" its origin. Location is not forwarded in the IP request.